# Interactive `ggplotly` graph is not plotted from inside `for` loop in `Rmd` file in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr, plotly, htmlwidgets

I tried to plot series of interactive `ggplotly` graphs from inside `for` loop in R markdown (`.Rmd`) file. Contents of  my `.Rmd` file:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(ggplot2) # for plots
library(plotly)  # for interactive plots

# Convert 4 variables to factor variables:
factor_vars <- c("vs", "am", "gear", "carb")
mtcars[factor_vars] <- data.frame(Map(as.factor, mtcars[factor_vars])) 



for (VAR in factor_vars) {
    cat(paste("Factor variable:", VAR))
    # Contents of "VAR" changes inside the loop
    p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x = "mpg", y = "wt", color = VAR)) + geom_point()

    # Print an interactive plot
    print(ggplotly(p))
}

```
````

I push `Knit HTML` button in `RStudio`. Unfortunately, none of interactive plots appear in the `.html` file.

**Question:** why the graphs aren't plotted? And how can I create interactive plot in combination with `for` loop in `Rmd` file?

p.s. If I use `print(p)` instead of `print(ggplotly(p))`, `ggplot2` plots appear in resulting `.html` file.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Based on this [github issue](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/273), you should be able to do something like this:

````
  ---
  title: "Untitled"
  output: html_document
  ---

  ```{r, message = F}
  library(ggplot2) # for plots
  library(plotly)  # for interactive plots

  # Convert 4 variables to factor variables:
  factor_vars <- c("vs", "am", "gear", "carb")
  mtcars[factor_vars] <- data.frame(Map(as.factor, mtcars[factor_vars])) 

  plt <- htmltools::tagList()
  i <- 1
  for (VAR in factor_vars) {

      # Contents of "VAR" changes inside the loop
      p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x = "mpg", y = "wt", color = VAR)) + 
        geom_point() + 
        ggtitle(paste("Factor variable:", VAR))


      # Print an interactive plot
      # Add to list
      plt[[i]] <- as.widget(ggplotly(p))
      i <- i + 1
  }

  ```

  ```{r, echo = F}
  plt
  ```
````

Comment: Nice workarround. Unfortunately, I'm not able to use it in my current automated analysis where in each iteration of `for` loop plots are followed by tables, results some statistical tests. Printing all plots in one place would be confusing. I noticed, that result of `pander()` also does not print from inside `for` loop. Is it some bug in `knitr`?

Comment: Looks like you raised your concern on the github repo as well. Probably best if you work with timelyportfolio on this.