# Several ggplotly figures from within if block in rmarkdown

Tags: ggplot2, r-markdown, plotly

I am unable to generate an html file, from rmarkdown, which displays two or more ggplotly plots created inside an if block in a given code chunk.

My MWE rmarkdown source code follows:

````
---
title: Several ggplotly figures from within if block in rmarkdown
author: "Mauricio Calvao"
date: "February 27, 2017"
output:
    html_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
```


## Outside if block:

I can have rmarkdown generate an html document with two ggplotly plots, outside of an if block in a given chunk:

```{r}
ggplotly(qplot(data = pressure, x = temperature, y = pressure))
ggplotly(qplot(data = pressure, x = pressure, y = temperature))
```

## Inside if block:

However, when I try the same code inside an if block, only the last plot shows up in the html document:

```{r}
if (TRUE) {
ggplotly(qplot(data = pressure, x = temperature, y = pressure))
ggplotly(qplot(data = pressure, x = pressure, y = temperature))
}
```



**How do I print two (or more plots, for that matter) from within an if block in the html document???**

The above is a MWE, but, in fact, in a more general setting I would have a large number of plots to be printed depending on several if else blocks...
````

Any suggestions are welcome!!

Comment: Maybe you could name each of your plot and use subplot to display two graphs for each of your page

Comment: Could [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37013876/interactive-ggplotly-graph-is-not-ploted-from-inside-for-loop-in-rmd-file?rq=1) question be relevant? Does the plot appear if you call it from within an `if` in a simple R script, not an Rmd chunk?

Comment: @MLavoie I tried subplot but could not manage for it to have a working layout: the legends of the 2 plots got mixed up> Besides, I would really like to have separate plots shown...

Comment: @juod: outside the if block both plots show up in the Viewer pane of RStudio (the environment I use), whereas inside the if block only the last one shows up in the Viewer :-(

Comment: @juod: the link you referred to above has a very contrived workaround. If no other cleaner suggestion appears, I might try it, though unwillingly...

Comment: I see. I don't have any specific solution for `plotly` in mind. Maybe splitting the plot into two chunks could be a non-elegant option? i.e. `{r} if (){ ggplotly } {r} if (){ ggplotly }`?

Comment: Worst case scenario would be making the plots separately, saving them somewhere, and retrieving the PNGs - sounds ugly, but I find that in practice it sometimes gives easier control on the size and placement of the resulting images, esp. if you want some tricky arrangement of figure parts.

Comment: I think the workaround described in the github issue [comments](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/273) would likely do the trick. Something like: `l <- htmltools::tagList()
for (i in 1:3) {
  l[[i]] <- plot_ly(x = rnorm(10))
}
l`, but generalized to your context with an if statement?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is now available from the [plotly reference](https://plot.ly/r/knitr/). 
In short, you either use:

- subplot:

  ```r
  if (TRUE) {
   p1= ggplotly(qplot(data = pressure, x = temperature, y = pressure))
   p2= ggplotly(qplot(data = pressure, x = pressure, y = temperature))
   subplot(p1, p2)
  }
  ```
- or taglist

  ```r
  if (TRUE) {
   p1= ggplotly(qplot(data = pressure, x = temperature, y = pressure))
   p2= ggplotly(qplot(data = pressure, x = pressure, y = temperature))
   htmltools::tagList(list(p1, p2))
  }
  ```

Comment: I do not understand the reason why not the whole block is executed. Moreover, the given link does not explain anything regarding the OP question.